# Multi select checkboxes and post request to API in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how do i multi select checkboxes and send the value of the checkboxes when all is selected and when a single checkbox is select using a post request to end point with this body below

```
   Column(children: [
                    Row(children: [
                      Text('select all'),
                      Checkbox(
                        value: value,
                        onChanged: (_) {},
                      )
                    ]),
                     Row(children: [
                      Text('user 1'),
                      Checkbox(
                        value: value1,
                        onChanged: (_) {},
                      )
                    ]),
                       Row(children: [
                      Text('user 2'),
                      Checkbox(
                        value: value2,
                        onChanged: (_) {},
                      )
                    ]),  
                  ]),
```

Post Request body

```
{
    "data": [{
       "id": "1",
       "isPresent": true
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "isPresent": true
    }]
}
```

Comment: you can add all selected value in `List`.

Comment: @JohnJoe i understand that part. i just need to see how it will look like

Comment: can't you multiple select the checkboxes now? I am a bit unclear on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I want click select all and a map containing the value of the checkbox and the text value will be sent to the post request method @JohnJoe

Comment: @namdi, I've read and re-read the question and your previous comment, but I can't understand what you mean. Please calm down and edit them. Use good punctuation and as many details to get yourself understood. Thanks!

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude this is a sample code. I want mark attendance for users by tapping the checkbox, however there is an option to check all (so that 'isPresent' can be updated to true when successfully sent to the server.) i need to know how to put together a map as mentioned above and sent in a data:[] through the post method to the server